Best Practices for Deploying Safe Wallets with the Same Address Across L1 and L2 Chains？
I'm working on deploying Safe wallets across both the Ethereum mainnet and Scroll with the same address. My need is to use the same address for cross-chain functionality such as bridging. Apologies if this question overlaps with previous discussions, but I haven’t found a clear explanation or best practices for relatively reliable functionality across both L1 and L2 chains, rather than just asset recovery solutions.
I've learned that this can be done by:

Deploying the Safe wallet on the first chain (e.g., Ethereum).
Replaying the deployment transaction on the second chain (Scroll in this case), using the same deployment address, calling the same proxy, and sending the same data.

This works, but I’ve encountered compatibility issues:

If you deploy the wallet on Ethereum mainnet (using the Safe website), it uses singleton=1.3.0 (0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552).

After replaying the transaction on Scroll, you get a functional wallet, but:

The Safe website warns: "This Safe Account was created with an unsupported base contract. The web interface might not work correctly. We recommend using the command line interface instead."
The transactions page of Safe web interface continually displays the submitted transaction as “indexing” for a long time (10–20 minutes) even after the transaction has already been confirmed on-chain.



I’ve seen some discussions from the Safe team explaining that this happens because the L1 version of the contract doesn't emit events like the L2 version, leading to slow indexing on the front end.
My questions are:

Can I first deploy the wallet on the L2 chain (Scroll) using singleton=1.3.0-L2 (0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E) and then replay the transaction on Ethereum mainnet?
Some explanation states the L2 version just adds new events and consumes more gas. I’d like to know if the replayed transaction would create a fully functional wallet on mainnet after using this method.

Should I deploy the wallet on the mainnet first and then replay the transaction on the L2 chain, followed by calling update_version_to_l2 in cli immediately?
I’ve seen this method mentioned in the docs, though I couldn’t find detailed instructions. My understanding is that this would update the wallet’s singleton to the L2 version while preserving the same address.


I hope to find a method that can work well for us, as my team can’t rely heavily on the CLI. Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You are correct with these assumptions; both the scenarios stated in your questions are valid. You can do either 1. or 2., at the expense of larger gas consumption, because the only difference between L1 and L2 contracts are events emitted and gas consumed. This explains also why it takes more time to index your transactions on an L2 with an L1 contract.
Please also be aware that whatever solution you will implement (the 1. looks best to me) will probably be temporary, as the Safe team is currently working on solving these issues in the upcoming version of the contracts (v1.5.0). I cannot give any estimate when this will be released, though.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

Many thanks for your detailed response, Louis! I have a quick follow-up: Would it be better to consistently use the 1.3.0 version across both chains, or would you recommend using 1.3.0-L2 on both instead?
Also when comparing these two approaches with deploying 1.3.0 first and calling update_version_to_l2 on L2, which option do you think might be preferable? I’d really appreciate any brief insights you can provide on the reasoning, as it would greatly help me explain this to my team.

Happy to help! 1. There is no ideal solution here, as it is a tradeoff between transaction prices on both chains vs. indexing times. If your users can afford to pay more even on mainnet, then you would go with L2 contracts on both; if on the contrary they cannot pay more and are ready to wait longer times on L2, then deploying L1 contracts on both chains would be more suitable. It really depends on your use case here! 2. If there is a possibility to use the CLI to update to L2 version after replaying each transaction from L1, then this would definitely be the way to go! I assumed you couldn't.
